# SecurityException: BC provider not installed

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

Writing code to generate Digital Certificate using `BouncyCastle`.

Here is the essential part of code causing problem.

```
public X509Certificate generateCertWithKeypair(KeyPair caPair)
            throws InvalidKeyException, SecurityException, SignatureException {
        X509V3CertificateGenerator v3CertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        v3CertGen
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        v3CertGen
                .setIssuerDN(new X509Principal("CN=cn, O=o, L=L, ST=il, C= c"));
        v3CertGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60
                * 60 * 24));
        v3CertGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10)));
        v3CertGen
                .setSubjectDN(new X509Principal("CN=cn, O=o, L=L, ST=il, C= c"));
        v3CertGen.setPublicKey(caPair.getPublic());
        v3CertGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");
        X509Certificate generateX509Certificate = v3CertGen
                .generateX509Certificate(caPair.getPrivate());//**here**
        return generateX509Certificate;
    }
```

Exception facing

```
Exception in "main" java.lang.SecurityException: BC provider not installed!
    at X509V3CertificateGenerator.generateX509Certificate(Unknown Source)
    at chapter4.Dupe.generateCertWithKeypair(Dupe.java:74)
    at chapter4.Dupe.main(Dupe.java:32)
```

In search I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516475/java-security-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-bc)  that  the latest jar resolves the issue, But no luck.

Am I missing something ?

[**See Full Code Here.**](http://pastebin.com/RcKNXfgF)

Comment: Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should "register" BC in JRE. You can do it in two ways: put bcprov.jar in $JRE/lib/ext folder and add in `$JRE/lib/security/java.security` line

> security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

or put bcprov.jar in classpath, don't modify java.security, but add in code somewhere

```
static { Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());  }
```

http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation

Comment: What I done is added the bouncy castle jar in lib folder. But not resolved. After this line added it registered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar issue, adding to the accepted answer, here is the solution worked for me.

Solution 1 :
Updating JRE/lib/security/java.security

```
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.4=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
```

The BC libraries needs to be on top (1&2)

Solution 2 :
Add it in the project

```
static {
 if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
                
       Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
  }

 if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
                Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 2);
 }
}
```